# Python multi function multithreading with threading.Thread? (variable number of threads)

Tags: python, multithreading, function, parallel-processing

I'm trying to start a variable number of threads to compute the results of functions for one of my automated trading modules. I have about 14 functions all of which are computationally expensive. I've been calculating each function sequentially, but it takes around 3 minutes to complete, and my platform is high frequency, I have the need to cut that computation time down to 1 minute or less.

I've read up on multiprocessing and multithreading, but I can't find a solution that fits my need.

What I'm trying to do is define "n" number of threads to use, then divide my list of functions into "n" groups, then compute each group of functions in a separate thread. Essentially:

```
functionList = [func1,func2,func3,func4]
outputList = [func1out,func2out,func3out,func4out]
argsList = [func1args,func2args,func3args,func4args]

# number of threads
n = 3

functionSplit = np.array_split(np.array(functionList),n)
outputSplit = np.array_split(np.array(outputList),n)
argSplit = np.array_split(np.array(argsList),n)
```

Now I'd like to start "n" seperate threads, each processing the functions according to the split lists. Then I'd like to name the output of each function according to the `outputList` and create a master dict of the outputs from each function. I then will loop through the output dict and create a dataframe with column ID numbers according to the information in each column (already have this part worked out, just need the multithreading).

Is there any way to do something like this? I've been looking into creating a subclass of the `threading.Thread` class and passing the functions, output names, and arguments into the `run()` method, but I don't know how to name and output the results of the functions from each thread! Nor do I know how to call functions in a list according to their corresponding arguments!

The reason that I'm doing this is to discover the optimum thread number balance between computational efficiency and time. Like I said, this will be integrated into a high frequency trading platform I'm developing where time is my major constraint!

Any ideas?

Comment: If your functions are CPU-bound then forget multithreading and look at multiprocessing (at least for CPython).

Comment: I'm realizing now that multiprocessing is the way to go. Any pointers on how to do this with the `process` module from `threading`?

Comment: `threading` is the wrong module. Use `multiprocessing`. `Pool.map` is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `multiprocessing` library like below

```
import multiprocessing

def callfns(fnList, argList, outList, d):
    for i in range(len(fnList)):
        d[somekey] = fnList[i](argList, outList)

...

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
d = manager.dict()
processes = []
for i in range(len(functionSplit)):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=callfns, args=(functionSplit[i], argSplit[i], outputSplit[i], d))
    processes.append(process)

for j in processes:
    j.start()

for j in processes:
    j.join()

# use d here
```

You can use a server process to share the dictionary between these processes. To interact with the server process you need `Manager`. Then you can create a dictionary in server process `manager.dict()`. Once all process join back to the main process, you can use the dictionary `d`.

I hope this help you solve your problem.

Comment: For more [here](https://shreyash14s.wordpress.com/2017/02/19/parallelism-in-python/)

Comment: Thank you! Each one of my functions will output a dataframe, is there any way that I can put the output of each function into a dict? Would I do this in the `callfuns` function and return the dict for each segment? Just not sure how this will work with multiple processes, if they finish at different times. Could you edit your answer to include this?

Comment: @denbjornen505 I have updated my answer as you said.

Answer (score 1):

- You should use `multiprocessing` instead of threading for cpu bound tasks.
- Manually creating and managing processes can be difficult and require more efforts. Do checkout the `concurrent.futures` and try the `ProcessPool` for maintaining a pool of processes. You can submit tasks to them and retrieve results.
- The [`Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) method from `multiprocessing` module can take a function and iterable and then process them in chunks in parallel to compute faster. The iterable is broken into separate chunks. These chunks are passed to the function in separate processes. Then the results are then put back together.